# WordPress site shows "Works and Days. August 1 — December 1." when I search for the site on Google

Tags: wordpress, seo

I have been working on a WordPress site for a client. When I search for the site on Google, it is the first site that comes up, but after the description of the site it says "Works and Days. August 1 — December 1." within the description. Does anyone know where this could be coming from and how I can get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Whoops - looks like the starter template the client was using included the "Works and Days" on a Page in the template. With that removed, it is gone from the search.